# Cannot assign the value of a textbox to a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read the value from a textbox and it returns nothing.

Within the console, it simply shows a white line, with the line number of the `console.log` statement.

```js
var amount = document.getElementById("billAmt").value;
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(amount);
});
```

```html
<input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
```

Comment: `amount` does not magically update. Put your `var` inside your event handler, where you actually want to use it.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting_

Comment: Welcome to SO. Feel free to delete the question since it is not really useful to anyone but you

Comment: @mpl This is more than a typo in `billamt`.

Comment: @deceze I can likely find a dupe if you want

Comment: @mpl Be my guest.

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500434/why-wont-this-simple-event-listener-work-in-javascript

Comment: Alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1. Typo in `billamt`. It should be `billAmt` in HTML or change either of them to make same
2. You need to get the value inside the `click` function.

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("billAmt").value;
  console.log(amount);

});
```

```html
<input id="billAmt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
```

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!